# textare a doesn't resize when I change "cols" parameter

Tags: html, forms, width, textarea

I have a textarea that i'd like to shrink in width: but no matter what I set the cols= parameter to, the textarea keeps its width. Why is this?
The code looks like

```
<textarea id="edit-submitted-question-request" name="submitted[question_request]" cols="10" rows="5" class="form-textarea required"></textarea>
```

and it can be found here:
http://quaaoutlodge.com/content/dinner-theatre-rock-romance

**EDIT A**

I commented out `width: 100%;` in `.form-textarea-wrapper textarea` in my css and now the `textarea` renders to the right size but the "resize bar" to extend the text area is still at 100%, why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Found a class in your css that makes problems for your textarea size:

```
.form-textarea-wrapper textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%; // <----- Thats the problem
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

width from that class is affecting on textareas. check your css file /system.base.css?nipcyw

Comment: @cerr Look for `.resizable-textarea .grippie` class and add a line `width:447px` if I'm correct ( play with the width abit ). Its just, in default css & html div class is automatically takes whole 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

you are using one div for the textarea in which you have set width as 100%, Please remove that width part then your cols=parameter will start working.

```
.form-textarea-wrapper textarea {
display: block;
margin: 0;
/* -------- width: 100%; ------- */ 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @cerr
Please do the required changes in your web page:

<pre>
.resizable-textarea .grippie {
  background: #eee url(../../misc/grippie.png) no-repeat center 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top-width: 0;
  cursor: s-resize;
  height: 9px;
  width: 447px;    <--------- Needs to be added------------->
  overflow: hidden;
</pre>

Also
<pre>
.form-textarea-wrapper textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto; <-----Earlier it was 100%, so change it is with auto or remove it----->
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
</pre>